# Update on union date column with a +/- 5 days range (min absolute value)

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, union

I'm trying to find a way to auto fill an SQL table with another SQL table on the basis of 4 parameters (I will implement this query into a stored procedure in a logic app system).

I have a logic app who insert automatically rows in a SQL table (from cognitive service source)
We'll call it **table1**:

**table1:**

| specs | brand | category | start_date | end_date | signal |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Xy-eee2 | mercury | alpha | 05/12/2021 | 16/12/2021 | NULL |
| Xd-FFF21 | venus | beta | 20/03/2021 | 25/04/2021 | NULL |

I want to fill this **table1** with the column "signal" present in **table2** (my cognitive service fill all the columns of table1 except "signal" - who appear NULL)

**table2:**

| brand | category | start_date | end_date | signal |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| mercury | alpha | 12/12/2021 | 15/12/2021 | action1 |
| venus | beta | 22/03/2021 | 20/04/2021 | action2 |
| mercury | alpha | 09/12/2021 | 20/12/2021 | action3 |
| mercury | alpha | 06/12/2021 | 17/12/2021 | action4 |

There are the 4 conditions to insert the data from table2.signal to table1.signal:

```
table1.brand = table2.brand  **AND**  
table1.category = table2.category **AND**  
table1.start_date (+/- 5 days range) = table2. start_date **AND**  
table1.end_date (+/- 5 days range)= table2. end_date
```

**Challenge:** I need to do the union on the date time by finding the min absolute value in 5 days range (negative or positive). The date will very rarely match into a simple equal between table1 and table2. Table2 date are the source of true and some **** people decided to not respect these date by starting the signal in a range of +/- 5 days in the table1

I started writing this code but I cannot see if my datetime range is possible:

```
UPDATE
   t1
SET
   t1.signal = t2.signal,
FROM
   table1 as t1,
   table2 as t2
WHERE
   t1.brand = t2.brand
   AND t1.category = t2.category
   AND t1.start_date = t2.start_date
   AND t1.end_date = t2.end_date
```

If everything works, then my **table1** example should receive the signal "action 4" on line 1 (action 1 and 2 date are out of range, and action 3 have a bigger absolute value date difference than action 4)
And my **table1** line 2 should receive the event action 2.

Many thanks by advance for those who'll find me a solution.

Comment: `FROM  table1 as t1,  table2 as t2`  No one should be using [old-style joins](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `DATEADD()` command to get the range.

```
UPDATE
   t1
SET
   t1.signal = t2.signal,
FROM
   table1 as t1,
   table2 as t2
WHERE
   t1.brand = t2.brand
   AND t1.category = t2.category
   AND t2.start_date BETWEEN DATEADD(day ,-5 ,t1.start_date) AND DATEADD(day ,5 ,t1.start_date)
   AND t2.end_date BETWEEN DATEADD(day ,-5 ,t1.end_date) AND DATEADD(day ,5 ,t1.end_date)
```